# Reset input:number after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below code to reset my form after submit.

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
        .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

However, I do have two input blocks that are unsupported which are `input:time` and `input:number`.

I found a workaround and added `input[name=action_time]` for the time block which work. However my number field has a more complex name `name=action[qty][]` so when adding `input[name=action[qty][]]` I get `syntax error`.

Comment: What about an `id` attribute?

Comment: you may reset it using the form id as `$('#your_form_id').trigger("reset");`

Comment: Actually just added `class` and looked for that instead which worked `id` will probably do it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset value to default ones, you need to reset the `form`, using `reset()` DOM native method, in your case:

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form[0].reset();
}
```

Or pass DOM node to method or directly called `formHTMLElement.reset()`

Comment: Good point. Didn't think about that. Think I will go with the method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complex names try to use quotes like following example :

```
$('input[name="action[qty][]"]').val('');
```

Or you can give your `input` a class attribute and use a class selector `.` to reset it :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="number" class='qty' name='action[qty][]' />
```

**JS :**

```
$('.qty').val('');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You aren't resetting values to default ones

Comment: Actually this work and answared the question. However I added `class` instead.

Comment: @Andreas I was guessing you were setting default value to inputs, apparently not

Comment: Good job @Andreas Using `class` is a more logical solution.

Comment: Didnt think about that until now. But you are right. I was about to add the default values back again to the resetform function. So you are right